# Which approach is best for storing a list of words in mysql that will later be used for statistics?

Tags: php, mysql, database

**DETAILS**

I have a quiz (let’s call it quiz1). Quiz1 uses the same wordlist each time it is generated.
If the user needs to, they can skip words to complete the quiz. I’d like to store those skipped words in mysql and then later perform statistics on them.

At first I was going to store the missed words in one column as a string. Each word would be separated by a comma.

```
|testid |       missedwords                     | score     |   userid  |
*************************************************************************
| quiz1 | wordlist,missed,skipped,words         |  59       |   1       |
| quiz2 | different,quiz,list                   |  65       |   1       |
```

The problem with this approach is that I want to show statistics at the end of each quiz about which words were most frequently missed by users who took quiz1.
I’m assuming that storing missed words in one column as above is inefficient for this purpose as I'd need to extract the information and then tally it -(probably tally using php- unless I stored that tallied data in a separate table).

I then thought perhaps I need to create a separate table for the missed words
The advantage of the below table is that it should be easy to tally the words from the table below.

```
|Instance|  missed word     |
*****************************
|   1    |  wordlist        |
|   1    |  missed          |
|   1    |  skipped         |
```

Another approach
I could create a table with tallys and update it each time quiz1 was taken.

```
Testid  |   wordlist|   missed| skipped| otherword|
**************************************************
Quiz1   |        1  |        1|       1| 0        |
```

The problem with this approach is that I would need a different table for each quiz, because each quiz will use different words. Also information is lost because only the tally is kept not the related data such which user missed which words.

**Question**

Which approach would you use? Why? Alternative approaches to this task are welcome. If you see any flaws in my logic please feel free to point them out.

**EDIT**
Users will be able to retake the quiz as many times as they like. Their information will not be updated, instead a new instance would be created for each quiz they retook.

Comment: Evidently `testid` is missing in table with `missed word`. If you did not intentionally present your question reduced, first check on databases, SQL.

Comment: Does the missed/skipped words have to be associated with specific users, or are you going for more anonymous stats? (you use two methodologies in your propositions, so more clarification may be needed in that regard.)

Comment: I'd like to keep as much information as possible, so I would like to keep missed words associated with the specific user. Later I plan on showing individual stats to the user (or at least having the option to develop that later).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have the word collection completely normalized. This way, analyses will be easy and fast.

```
quiz_words with wordID, word
quiz_skipped_words with quizID, userID, wordID
```

To get all the skipped words of a user:

```
SELECT wordID, word 
FROM quiz_words 
JOIN quiz_skipped_words USING (wordID) 
WHERE userID = ?;
```

You could add a group by clause to have group counts of the same word.

To get the count of a specific word:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM quiz_words 
WHERE word LIKE '?';
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [*database normalization theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), second approach is better, because ideally one relational table cell should store only one value, which is atomic and unsplitable. Each word is an entity instance.

Also, I might suggest to not create `Quiz-Word` tables, but reserve another column in `Missed-Word` table for quiz, for which this word was specified, then use this column as a foreign key for `Quiz` table. Then you probably may avoid real time table generation (which is a "bad practice" in database design).

Answer (score 1):

why not have a quiz table and quiz_words table, the quiz_words table would store id,quizID,word as columns. Then for each quiz instance create records in the quiz_words table for each word the user did use.

You could then run mysql counts on the quiz_words table based on quizID and or quiz type

Answer (score 1):

The best solution (from my pov) for what are you trying to achieve is the normalized aproach:

- `test` table which has `test_id` column and other columns
- `missed_words` table which has `id` (AI PK) and `word` (UQ) , **here you can also have a `hits` column that should be incremented each time that a association to this word is made in `test_missed_words` table**  this way you have the stats that you want already compiled and you don't need them to be calculated from a select query
- `test_missed_words` which is a link table that has `test_id` and `missed_word_id` (composite PK)

This way you do not have redundant data (missed words) and you can extract easily that stats that you want

Answer (score 1):

Keeping as much information as possible (and being able to compile user-specific stats later as well as overall stats now) I would create a table structure similar to:

```
                  Stats
quizId  |   userId  |     type|    wordId|
******************************************
1       |        1  |   missed|         4|
1       |        1  |  skipped|         7|
```

Where `type` can either be an `int` defining the different types of actions, or a string representation - depending on if you believe it can ever be more. ^^

Then:

```
     Quizzes
quizId  |  quizName|
********************
       1|    Quiz 1|
```

With the word list made for each quiz like:

```
     WordList (pk: wordId)
quizId  |   wordId|   word|
***************************
      1 |       1 |    Cat|
      1 |       2 |    Dog|
```

You would have your `user` table however you want, we are just linking the `id` from it in to this system.

With this, all `id` fields will be non-unique keys in the `stats` table.  When a user skips or misses a word, you would add the `id` of that word to the `stats` table along with relevant `quizId` and `type`.  Getting stats this way would make it easy as a `per-user` basis, a `per-word` basis, or a `per-type` basis - or a combination of the three.  It will also make the word list for each quiz easily available as well for making the quizzes. ^^

Hope this helps!